# Ensure left-floated element isn't last in row?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to come up with a way to ensure that a specific left-floated element isn't the last in a row, and drops to a new line if that would be the case.

The best way to handle this I figure would be to detect whether or not there were enough space between the element and the right side of the window for another element to fit (a known distance, 160px say), and if not, to drop this element to the next line.  Is this possible with CSS?  JS would be okay but if I could do this with CSS that would be preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: @Joseph Not sure why you'd need any.  What's unclear about the question?

Comment: @NaOH: because if you provide us for example a simplified http://jsfiddle.net/ example, we can start playing with it immediately `->` more/better/sooner results for you :)

Comment: @biziclop Here you go, I guess... http://jsfiddle.net/dq74k/1/

Comment: It's not so easy, I'm playing with things like http://jsfiddle.net/3xgyN/ Practically you want a conditional `clear:left`.

Comment: ok, I give up. http://jsfiddle.net/3xgyN/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent this is a solution to your problem - [jsfiddle.net/avrelian/Dh86D/](http://jsfiddle.net/avrelian/Dh86D/)

```
#special { 
    background-color:green; 
    margin:0 170px 5px 0;
}
#special + .left-float {
    background-color:blue;
    margin-left: -165px;
}
```

It fails if your wrapper element has the width less than the double width of your floating elements, since the floating element next to your special element will not be shown.

Comment: This is genius!  It appears to work exactly as intended.  I will implement it and let you know how I make out.  Thank you!

Comment: @avrelain This is very, very close to working perfectly.  See [here](http://www.element17.com).  The only issue I'm running into is that the following element isn't always the same width (but is going to be one of only 3 different widths).  Without resorting to jquery, is there any way to have it use the width of the preceding element as the value for the margin?

Comment: Sorry, but there is no "previous sibling" CSS selector. So we cannot examine the width of a next floating element. All that may be done in this situation is to use three different CSS classes, say "before_narrow", "before_normal", and "before_wide". Of course, you should use jQuery to set them properly. Please, see updated solution - [jsfiddle.net/avrelian/Dh86D/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/avrelian/Dh86D/1/)

Comment: Not a problem, I've got this working acceptably with a bit of PHP hackery.  Thanks for all your help!